# Java -JsonArray.contains(string) no such function?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSONArray called playtitles, and a String called playname.
I want to iterate through the JSONArray and check for the String, but JSONArray doesn't have a .contains() function, this is the relevant code:

This is the error I get `The method contains(String) is undefined for the type JSONArray`

I have tried converting playName to a JSON string but that doesn't seem to work either.
I have also tried using an ArrayList and then converting it to a JSONArray but that causes more problems.

Any tips?

Comment: What package does this JSONArray come from?

Comment: not sure what you mean I'm using the JSON jar

Comment: There is no class named JSONArray in the standard Java libraries. Either tell us where it comes from or - if it's your own class - provide the source for it. Otherwise the only answer anyone can give here is that JSONArray does not provide a .contains()-Method. Which is what the compiler already told you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the following implementation:

```
http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/
```

According to their specification, there is a .contains() method for JSONArray.

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

So the import would be something like :

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
```

Comment: I downloaded the jar, added it to the build path as an external jar, and when I try the import I get this error - 'The import net.sf.JSONArray cannot be resolved' Don't know what I'm doing wrong @demostene

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using *org.json.JSONArray*:

Yes, no such method. You will need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Could also be org.primefaces.json.JSONArray. Same answer though. ;)